# How can I add item number on the cart icon at at appBar icon in flutter? And how can I make it animate adding new item?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I want to add item numbers on the cart icon in flutter like this in picture, and want to animate while adding new item to cart. My cart icon is in appBar.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be achieved by this piece of code in appBar.

```
appBar: new AppBar(

    actions: <Widget>[

      new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

        child: new Container(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 30.0,
          child: new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder:(BuildContext context) =>
                      new CartItemsScreen()
                  )
              );
            },

            child: new Stack(

              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Colors.white,),
                    onPressed: null,
                ),
                list.length ==0 ? new Container() :
                new Positioned(

                    child: new Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                            Icons.brightness_1,
                            size: 20.0, color: Colors.green[800]),
                        new Positioned(
                            top: 3.0,
                            right: 4.0,
                            child: new Center(
                              child: new Text(
                                list.length.toString(),
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 11.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),


                      ],
                    )),

              ],
            ),
          )
        )

        ,)],
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use [badges package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges).

Example:

```
Chip(
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  label: Text('BADGE', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
),
Badge(
  badgeColor: Colors.deepPurple,
  shape: BadgeShape.square,
  borderRadius: 20,
  toAnimate: false,
  badgeContent:
      Text('BADGE', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this package. It is simple and easy to use.

```
Badge(
   badgeContent: Text('3'),
   child: Icon(Icons.settings),
)
```

[Badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple and modified code from above. Did a few minor changes

```
actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 35.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // Todo:navigate to cart screen
                  if (kDebugMode) {
                    print("tapped on cart icon");
                  }
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart_sharp,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null,
                    ),
                    1 == 0
                        ? Container()
                        : Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 20.0,
                                  width: 20.0,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: kTextColorSecondary,
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  ),
                                  child: const Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "10",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: kTextColor,
                                        fontSize: 11.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Add Stock"),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: [
      Badge(
        position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 3, end: 18),
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
        badgeContent: Text(
          '3',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0),
            onPressed: () {}),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[Number of Items Shown on Shopping cart items in Ap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL4BZ.png)

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("STORE"),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart_rounded,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 4,
              right: 6,
              child: Container(
                height: 22,
                width: 22,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
                child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "12",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 11,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.settings)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert_rounded)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use Stack As  above to show the number of products added to cart right on the Icon (Shopping Cart).